# Mongodb - PHP - Insert as number

Tags: php, string, mongodb, integer

I have a php script that looks like this:

```
    $contacts["{$firstname}"]    =  $_POST["{$firstname}"] ;
$contacts["{$lastname}"]    =  $_POST["{$lastname}"] ;
$contacts["{$age}"]    =  $_POST["{$age}"] ;


    $collection->insert($contacts);
```

so this works fine but i all of these values are going into my collection as "fistname", "lastname" and "age" with quotes around all.  I want the quotes around first name and last name but i want the age field to insert as a number/integer not a quoted string.  How do I make sure that the age field and other numeric fields go into the mongodb/collection as a number?

I was thinking something like: integer -> $_POST["{$age}"] but im sure that's not right. Again im using PHP not the shell.  Thnaks.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How can you verify that whatever string `$firstname` stores is available in $_POST? Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you don't need all those quotes and braces. Second, try casting the value to an `int`

```
$contacts = array(
    $firstname => $_POST[$firstname],
    $lastname  => $_POST[$lastname],
    $age       => (int) $_POST[$age]
);
```

I'm assuming here that all the `$_POST` vars have been checked and validated and `$firstname`, `$lastname` and `$age` are all valid array key strings

Comment: I tried your suggestion and although i am not getting any page errors it is still inserting as a "" string.  Any other suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Ooops, this did work.  I actually had an error in my code.  Once i fixed the error (int) worked perfectly.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if there is a cheat sheet on these function like (int).  Now my problem is i want to keep the decimal and the numbers after the decmal but (int) is stripping everything after the decimal.  What function would i use to keep the decimal in there and the number after the decimal.  Thanks.

Comment: Cheat Sheet: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#languag

Comment: @user982853 `(int)` isn't a function, it's a type cast. Try `(double)` for a decimal number

Answer (score 1):

Simple, typecast to integer, and then do the insert:

```
$contacts["{$age}"]    =  intval($_POST["{$age}"]) ;
$collection->insert($contacts);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and although i am not getting any page errors it is still inserting as a "" string. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php to convert a string to an integer.